# WxWidgets crash. App is run from cmdLine with some cmdLine args. wxCriticalSectionLocker seems to run in a loop until it crashes. This occur randomly

Tags: wxwidgets, critical-section

Running an application from cmd with some cmdLine args. WxWidget parses the arguments and passes them to my application. Some methods are run in my app based on those params and than the app finishes. In some cases WxWidget crashes with the following stack. Any suggestions on why this might happen?

```
0x1022e0184 std::__1::__compressed_pair_elem<std::__1::basic_string<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::__1::allocator<wchar_t> >::__rep, 0, false>::__get() const + 4 (compressed_pair.h:67)
1   0x1022e0175 std::__1::__compressed_pair<std::__1::basic_string<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::__1::allocator<wchar_t> >::__rep, std::__1::allocator<wchar_t> >::first() const + 21 (compressed_pair.h:156)
2   0x1022e0095 std::__1::basic_string<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::__1::allocator<wchar_t> >::__is_long() const + 21 (string:1459)
3   0x1022e0369 std::__1::basic_string<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::__1::allocator<wchar_t> >::size() const + 25 (string:978)
4   0x1022e0e95 std::__1::basic_string<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::__1::allocator<wchar_t> >::length() const + 21 (string:979)
5   0x1022ddbd5 wxString::length() const + 21 (string.h:1405)
6   0x1020f3ca8 wxPrivate::wxStringAsBufHelper<wchar_t>::Get(wxString const&, unsigned long*) + 40 (string.h:3796)
7   0x1020f3c34 wxCharTypeBuffer<wchar_t> wxString::tchar_str<wchar_t>(unsigned long*) const + 52 (string.h:1627)
8   0x1020f3af5 wxStringTypeBufferBase<wchar_t>::wxStringTypeBufferBase(wxString&, unsigned long) + 69 (string.h:3906)
9   0x1020f3aa5 wxStringTypeBuffer<wchar_t>::wxStringTypeBuffer(wxString&, unsigned long) + 37 (string.h:3990)
10  0x1020ee785 wxStringTypeBuffer<wchar_t>::wxStringTypeBuffer(wxString&, unsigned long) + 37 (string.h:3990)
11  0x1020ee612 wxString::FromAscii(char const*, unsigned long) + 98 (string.cpp:1169)
12  0x1020ee80c wxString::FromAscii(char const*) + 60 (string.cpp:1187)
13  0x102155f0a wxMutexInternal::HandleLockResult(int) + 266 (threadpsx.cpp:371)
14  0x102155dc4 wxMutexInternal::Lock() + 100 (threadpsx.cpp:305)
15  0x10215ec57 wxMutex::Lock() + 151 (thrimpl.cpp:43)
16  0x101c30c65 wxCriticalSection::Enter() + 21 (thread.h:291)
17  0x101c30c43 wxCriticalSectionLocker::wxCriticalSectionLocker(wxCriticalSection&) + 35 (thread.h:307)
18  0x101c2d09d wxCriticalSectionLocker::wxCriticalSectionLocker(wxCriticalSection&) + 29 (thread.h:306)
19  0x1020cc870 wxLog::GetComponentLevel(wxString const&) + 32 (log.cpp:630)
20  0x1022dddcb wxLog::IsLevelEnabled(unsigned long, wxString const&) + 59 (log.h:419)
21  0x102155f1f wxMutexInternal::HandleLockResult(int) + 287 (threadpsx.cpp:371)
22  0x102155dc4 wxMutexInternal::Lock() + 100 (threadpsx.cpp:305)
23  0x10215ec57 wxMutex::Lock() + 151 (thrimpl.cpp:43)
24  0x101c30c65 wxCriticalSection::Enter() + 21 (thread.h:291)
25  0x101c30c43 wxCriticalSectionLocker::wxCriticalSectionLocker(wxCriticalSection&) + 35 (thread.h:307)
26  0x101c2d09d wxCriticalSectionLocker::wxCriticalSectionLocker(wxCriticalSection&) + 29 (thread.h:306)
27  0x1020cc870 wxLog::GetComponentLevel(wxString const&) + 32 (log.cpp:630)
28  0x1022dddcb wxLog::IsLevelEnabled(unsigned long, wxString const&) + 59 (log.h:419)
29  0x102155f1f wxMutexInternal::HandleLockResult(int) + 287 (threadpsx.cpp:371)
30  0x102155dc4 wxMutexInternal::Lock() + 100 (threadpsx.cpp:305)
31  0x10215ec57 wxMutex::Lock() + 151 (thrimpl.cpp:43)
32  0x101c30c65 wxCriticalSection::Enter() + 21 (thread.h:291)
33  0x101c30c43 wxCriticalSectionLocker::wxCriticalSectionLocker(wxCriticalSection&) + 35 (thread.h:307)
34  0x101c2d09d wxCriticalSectionLocker::wxCriticalSectionLocker(wxCriticalSection&) + 29 (thread.h:306)
35  0x1020cc870 wxLog::GetComponentLevel(wxString const&) + 32 (log.cpp:630)
36  0x1022dddcb wxLog::IsLevelEnabled(unsigned long, wxString const&) + 59 (log.h:419)
37  0x102155f1f wxMutexInternal::HandleLockResult(int) + 287 (threadpsx.cpp:371)
38  0x102155dc4 wxMutexInternal::Lock() + 100 (threadpsx.cpp:305)
39  0x10215ec57 wxMutex::Lock() + 151 (thrimpl.cpp:43)
40  0x101c30c65 wxCriticalSection::Enter() + 21 (thread.h:291)
41  0x101c30c43 wxCriticalSectionLocker::wxCriticalSectionLocker(wxCriticalSection&) + 35 (thread.h:307)
42  0x101c2d09d wxCriticalSectionLocker::wxCriticalSectionLocker(wxCriticalSection&) + 29 (thread.h:306)
43  0x1020cc870 wxLog::GetComponentLevel(wxString const&) + 32 (log.cpp:630)
44  0x1022dddcb wxLog::IsLevelEnabled(unsigned long, wxString const&) + 59 (log.h:419)
45  0x102155f1f wxMutexInternal::HandleLockResult(int) + 287 (threadpsx.cpp:371)
46  0x102155dc4 wxMutexInternal::Lock() + 100 (threadpsx.cpp:305)
47  0x10215ec57 wxMutex::Lock() + 151 (thrimpl.cpp:43)
48  0x101c30c65 wxCriticalSection::Enter() + 21 (thread.h:291)
```

Could not find any relevant solutions or indication of why this might occur.
Application does not have any UI.

Comment: what wx version? What OS? What parameters you give when it crashes and when it's not?

Comment: WX version: 3.1 OS: MacOs
About the parameters: are custom params for my application, same parameters when it crashes and when it does not.

Comment: is there a pattern of when it crashes? Does it crash every time at the same place? Do you use threads and proper locking mechanism?

Comment: I can not see any pattern. It looks like a random crash.

Comment: do you use threads? Can you try to run the program without parameters? Couple of times?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `pthread_mutex_lock()` fails with an unexpected error (i.e. not one of `EDEADLK`, `EINVAL` or `ETIMEDOUT`) and trying to log this error results in the same error again and, so, to stack overflow (making this site a good choice for discussing this!).

It would be interesting to know what is the value passed to `HandleLockResult()`, i.e. what is the actual error, if you can look it up. And, of course, if you can provide simple example reproducing the problem, you should open a bug report in wxWidgets for this.

Comment: I will try to see the value passed in 'HandleLockResult()'. It is weird because when I force return false from `static bool IsLevelEnabled(wxLogLevel level, const wxString& component)` the crash does not appear anymore. It seems that `wxLogLevel wxLog::GetComponentLevel(const wxString& componentOrig)` is the method that causes the loop and crash. I will come back with the value passed to `HandleLockResult()`

Comment: It seems that in `HandleLockResult()` the value passed is 22 (EINVAL) and it goes into `wxString wxString::FromAscii(const char *ascii)` where `ascii` is "wx" and execution enters here: 
`wxStringInternalBuffer(wxString& str, size_t lenWanted = 1024)
        : wxStringTypeBufferBase<wxStringCharType>(str, lenWanted) {}` with `str` is "" and `lenWanted` is 2 and from here on the execution gets into this method:
`static wxScopedWCharBuffer Get(const wxString& s, size_t *len)` and here is BAD_ACCESS

Comment: Oops, sorry, I overlooked that `EINVAL` resulted in `wxLogDebug()` call too. The really interesting question is why does it happen the first time. Could you put a breakpoint on this line and check which mutex is being locked when this happens for the *first* time?

Comment: I will check this out and come back. My question now would be the following: in wx log.h what do I break if I force disable the logging? I would achieve this by changing the `IsEnabled()` method as follow:
    `static bool IsEnabled()
    {
  return false;
#if wxUSE_THREADS
        if ( !wxThread::IsMain() )
            return IsThreadLoggingEnabled();
#endif // wxUSE_THREADS

        return ms_doLog;
    }`
I do not use the wx logging and it seems that by doing this everything works just fine for now.

Comment: You should still be interested in knowing why does locking the mutex fail originally, this is really not expected and may be a symptom of another problem, that you do care about, even if you don't care about logging.